# Sequelize report too many connections at some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize in my nodejs.app to load and save data.
To manange Sequelize I use:

(Sample model)

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config/mysql");

const login = sequelize.define(
  "login_bot",
  {
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    // Model attributes are defined here
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    team: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);

module.exports = login;
```

The config for this is:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", {
  host: "xxx.bplaced.net",
  dialect: "mariadb",
  pool: {
    max: 25,
    min: 5,
    idle: 20000,
    evict: 15000,
    acquire: 30000,
  },
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection to database has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to database:", err);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

In my code I use: as sample

```
    const logindata = await login.findAll({
      where: { team: usersdata[0].team },
      attributes: ["login", "password"],
      raw: true,
    });
```

All works fine. But after some time I get "too many connections" from the server. So I want to ask whether the workflow is wring and I miss to close the DBConnection some where?

I have in all 4 models. All models with "..config/mysql.js" as reference. Do Sequelize open for each model a connection and keeps this open? Or just one connection for the whole app?
In all I just want to have one connection my app is using all the time.

Or do I have to close Sequelize somewhere at each call? Hope to get some hints here because iam lost at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application needs to retrieve data from the database, it creates a database connection. Creating this connection involves some overhead of time and machine resources for both your application and the database. Many database libraries and ORM's will try to reuse connections when possible, so that they do not incur the overhead of establishing that DB connection over and over again. The pool is the collection of these saved, reusable connections that, in your case, Sequelize pulls from. Your configuration of

```
pool: {
     max: 5,
     min: 0,
     idle: 10000
}
```

reflects that your pool should:

Never have more than five open connections (max: 5)

At a minimum, have zero open connections/maintain no minimum number of connections (min: 0)

Remove a connection from the pool after the connection has been idle (not been used) for 10 seconds (idle: 10000)